# Why are `Item`s of a `Char` iterator, obtained from calling `chars` on a string slice, not references to `char`s?

Tags: rust

Running the following code will cause the compiler to complain that `PairedNumbers::get` returns `(char, char)` and not `(&char, &char)`:

```
use std::iter::{Zip, Cycle, Skip};
use std::str::Chars;

struct PairedNumbers<'a> {
    char_pairs: Zip<Cycle<Chars<'a>>, Skip<Cycle<Chars<'a>>>>,
    counter: usize,
}

impl<'a, 'b: 'a> PairedNumbers<'a> {
    fn new(num_str: &'b str, jump: usize) -> PairedNumbers<'a> {
        PairedNumbers {
            char_pairs: num_str.chars().cycle().zip(num_str.chars().cycle().skip(jump)),
            counter: 0,
        }
    }

    fn get(&'a mut self) -> (&'a char, &'a char) {
        self.counter = self.counter + 1;
        self.char_pairs.next().expect("could not get char pair from unparsed_pairs!")
    }
}
```

We see that the `PairedNumbers` struct is initialized by making iterators (`Chars` to be specific) over the characters of the string slice. Given that `&str` is a reference to a particular region of memory (I am assuming a contiguous region?), wouldn't `Chars` really be iterating over references to the the component `char`s that make up the `str`? Is Rust's auto-dereferencing at play here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#textual-types) points to an UTF-8 encoded sequence of characters; as they are encoded you cannot get an iterator resulting in references to the decoded characters, the decoded character need to be returned by value.

Also see the `Item` type of the [`Iterator` impl for `std::str::Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#impl-Iterator).

Comment: Does this mean that each time I call `Chars` on the `&str`, I am creating a new copy of decoded characters?

Comment: Yes, but the decoded characters are not stored at the same time (unless you do it yourself).  Decoding them obviously involves some cpu cycles, but the iterator returns them one by one. Calling `chars()` just creates the iterator, the characters are only actually decoded if you walk it, i.e. call `next()` until it's done.